# Using generics restricts me to using a specific type while I want to use all possible subclasses of that type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have the following code, which ended up this way due to other constraints:

```
public interface Action { }

public interface Result { }

public interface Player<A extends Action, R extends Result, P extends Player<A, R, P>> { }

public interface Game<A extends Action, R extends Result, P extends Player<A, R, P>> { }

abstract public class AbstractGame<A extends Action, R extends Result, P extends Player<A, R, P>> implements Game<A, R, P> { }

public class RPSGame<P extends RPSPlayer<P>> extends AbstractGame<RPSGesture, RPSResult, P> { }
```

Other relevant classes/interfaces:

```
abstract public class GesturePlayer<A extends Action, R extends Result, P extends GesturePlayer<A, R, P>> implements Player<A, R, P> { }

abstract public class RPSPlayer<P extends RPSPlayer<P>> extends GesturePlayer<RPSGesture, RPSResult, P> { }

public class RPSHumanPlayer extends RPSPlayer<RPSHumanPlayer> { }

public class RPSSimpleAIPlayer extends RPSPlayer<RPSSimpleAIPlayer> { }

public enum RPSGesture implements Gesture, Action, GestureFPSRules { }

public enum RPSResult implements Result { }
```

Then I noticed that, due to all changes, I am using raw types in my program, which I do not want at all:

```
private void init() {
    RPSGame rpsGame = new RPSGame();
    rpsGame.addPlayer(new RPSHumanPlayer());
    rpsGame.addPlayer(new RPSSimpleAIPlayer());
    rpsGame.playGame();
}
```

Here `RPSGame` is a raw type, while I initially intended it to be raw, it got generics added to it to keep the code working.

The problem is that I cannot make it non-generic as then the code does not compile anymore with everything that I have tried, therefore is it possible to:

- Either remove the generics from the `RPSGame` class?
- Or define `RPSGame rpsGame` in such a way (with typed parameters), that it compiles?

Comment: Looks like you're gotten a little trigger happy with the generics. I would start again and try to work out _exactly_ where you need generics. I can't even begin to make heads or tails of the (mostly circular) declarations.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I feel pretty much the same, the only places where I really need the generics are mainly `A extends Action` and `R extends Result`, and the rest are sort of hotfixes... And this is why I am still busy designing the project structure.

Comment: I would say your main issue is the circular declaration of `Player` as `Player<A, R, P>`. This is obviously making it impossible to declare a generic player type. Can you remove that from the `Player`? It seems that you always declare it to extends itself, i.e. it is always `Player<X extends Player<X>>` - this might well be redundant.

Comment: Generics are a way to help ensure that you don't mix the "wrong" types together -- somewhat of the opposite of what you're trying to do.  You've shown the classes/interfaces and the type parameters, but you haven't shown how you actually *use* the generics in your player, action, game, result APIs.  I'm not sure that generics are the answer to whatever problem it was that made you decide to use them in this particular case.

Comment: You may want to look into more traditional solutions like the [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) Design Patterns for a start.  These can help you take advantage of polymorphism, where generics tends to try and prevent the "mixed bag" of implementations that you're looking for.